# Pulling through Twitter avatar with tweet

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

im pulling through my latest tweet onto my hompage but i dont know what i need to add to also pull through the avatar.

any ideas?

```
 <script src="http://twitterjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/twitter.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 getTwitters('tweet', {
id: 'gezzamondo',
count: 1,
enableLinks: true,
ignoreReplies: true,
clearContents: true,
template: '"%text%" <a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%/">%time%</a>'
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
 %user_profile_image_url%
```

in the template variables, that should get your avatar.

so it would be

```
 template: '"%text%" <img src="%user_profile_image_url%" height="" width="" /><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id%/">%time%</a>'
```

More info see here,

[source](http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/)